# Is there a maximum number of Tables allowed in Play 2.0 framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi So I have created a quick table:

```
package models;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity
public class Phone extends Model {
@Id
public Long phoneID;
public String group;
public String name;
}
```

and i get the following error:

> PersistenceException: Error getting sequence nextval
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error getting sequence nextval
>        com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.getMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:213)
>        com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.loadMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:163)
>        com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.nextId(SequenceIdGenerator.java:118)
>        com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptor.nextId(BeanDescriptor.java:1218)
>        com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.setIdGenValue(DefaultPersister.java:1304)
>        com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:403)
>        com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveEnhanced(DefaultPersister.java:345)
>        com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveRecurse(DefaultPersister.java:315)
>        com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.save(DefaultPersister.java:282)
>        com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1577)
>        com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1567)
>        com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.save(Ebean.java:538)  play.db.ebean.Model.save(Model.java:76)
>        models.Command.createCommand(Command.java:100)
>        models.Command.populateCommands(Command.java:68)
>        Global.onStart(Global.java:22)  play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onStart(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:15)
>        play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(Global.scala:134)
>        play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60)
>        play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60)
>        scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
>        scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
>        play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:60)
>        play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:125)
>        play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
>        scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
>        play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
>        play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110)
>        scala.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:277)
>        play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110)
>        play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110)
>        akka.dispatch.Future$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:195)
>        akka.dispatch.Future$$anon$3.run(Future.scala:194)
>        akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:83)
>        akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1381)
>        akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
>        akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
>        akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
>        akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)

is there a maximum number of tables I'm allowed using the h2 memory database? I don't really understand where this error comes from. If i remove this line it works fine, but it looks like another class is causing the issues: createCommand, which just has the following:

```
public static void create(Command data) {
    data.save();
}
public static void populateCommands() {
    createCommand(0x00, "Cmd1");
    createCommand(0x02, "Cmd2");
    createCommand(0x03, "Cmd3");
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `group` is a keyword in most of databases, so change its name to phonesGroup or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that I had eclipse open.
I have noticed some problems with eclipse and play running at the same time.
I needed to close eclipse run the play framework and the open eclipse again.